# Is exclusive breastfeeding better than breast milk+formula, in developed countries?

Tags: nutrition, milk, parenting

I would like to know whether exclusive breastfeeding is shown to be better than a combination of breast milk and formula, in developed countries.

The current advice of the World Health Organization (WHO) is that six months of [exclusive breastfeeding](http://www.who.int/nutrition/topics/exclusive_breastfeeding/en/) leads to best health outcomes for the child. This means that the child is fed on demand, only with breast milk, for a full six months. Solid foods and liquids other than milk are not recommended.

I have seen this same recommendation on all the baby websites I've looked at ([here is one example](http://www.babycentre.co.uk/baby/breastfeeding/howlong/)), and it has been repeated to me by a pediatrician, different nurses, and a lactation specialist, all in The Netherlands.

Formula-feeding (with no breast milk alongside it) leads to [more hospitalizations](http://adc.bmj.com/content/94/2/148.full) for gastric and breathing problems.

However, there are two ways to *non-exclusively* breastfeed:

1) Introduce solid food before an infant is a full six months old. Evidence from the UK suggests that introducing solids earlier than six months has [no adverse health outcomes](http://adc.bmj.com/content/94/2/148.full). In fact, children who are exclusively breastfed are at a higher risk for [iron deficiency](http://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.c5955).

2) Introduce formula alongside breast milk. This is the topic I am interested in.

I am looking for evidence that compares *exclusive* breastfeeding to *half-breast milk, half-formula*, in developed countries.

The WHO has to give recommendations that are not only simple and clear, but that pertain to the whole world. I am skeptical about how well this recommendation for exclusive breastfeeding translates into the wellbeing of children in developed countries. Is there evidence to support the WHO's recommendations?

Comment: One noted side effect of introducing formula through a bottle is that it apparently (citation needed) interferes with a baby's ability to learn to latch onto the breast, thus reducing the possibility of breast feeding.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that.

Comment: This study is about PRETERM what about FULLTERM!?. Preterms are susceptible to these diseases and in need for intensive care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This prospective study  in the UK found a serious risk of neonatal necrotising enterocolitis amongst formula-users.

- A. Lucas, T.J. Cole. [Breast milk and neonatal necrotising enterocolitis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0140673690933048), The Lancet,
  Volume 336, Issues 8730–8731, 22 December 1990, Pages 1519–1523

> In a prospective multicentre study on 926 preterm infants formally assigned to their early diet, necrotising enterocolitis developed in 51 (5·5%). Mortality was 26% in stringently confirmed cases. In exclusively formula-fed babies confirmed disease was 6-10 times more common than in those fed breast milk alone and **3 times more common than in those who received formula plus breast milk**. Pasteurised donor milk seemed to be as protective as raw maternal milk.

I tried to read this report which looked at meta-analyses on breastfeeding research, which seemed very relevant, but was unable to confirm from it whether this stood up to further review.

- [Breastfeeding and Maternal and Infant Health Outcomes in Developed Countries](http://www.ahrq.gov/downloads/pub/evidence/pdf/brfout/brfout.pdf), Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality, U.S. Department of Health and Human Services, April 2007.

Note: This only looks at one type of problem, and is not a measure of overall health outcomes of the child and mother. It also doesn't show causality.

Comment: Wait! Pure formula is 6-10 times worse than breast-feeding, and 3 times worse than a mixture of both. That is *suggestive* that a mixed approach is about twice as bad as breast feeding, BUT that difference, paradoxically, might not be statistically significant. Would need to see the paper's results to confirm.

Comment: Is there anything there that shows the effect on other infants (not preterm)?